# InsertAfter after certain amount of elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Is it possible to insert html after a certain amount of elements with javascript, as example:

```
<content>
  <article class=“art”>Some content 1</article>
  <article class=“art”>Some content 2</article>
  <article class=“art”>Some content 3</article>
  <article class=“art”>Some content 4</article>
</content>
```

I’d like to insert some html after the 3rd article.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: You mean like this? https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/PoaKVdz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("article:nth-of-type(3)").append("what you like");
```

its for jquery in fact
for javascript:

```
var thirdElement = document.querySelector(".art article:nth-of-type(3)")
thirdElement.append("what you like to append")
```

Comment: I made some little fixes to the code, which are waiting for approval